# Firebase REST API signInWithCustomToken and Apple SignIn Provider

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, sign-in-with-apple

## Context

- iOS app written in Swift for iOS 13.2 (does NOT use Firebase iOS SDK)
- App uses Firebase Realtime Database via REST calls (so needs an ID token from
  Firebase Authentication)

I am trying to switch my iOS App to using Apple's "Sign in with Apple" feature, to replace the simple username / password authentication through the Firebase Authentication's "Email/Password" Sign-in provider .

A successful "Apple sign-in" by the user will leave me with a JWT token (identity token) from Apple, such as this one (decoded & edited) :

```
HEADER

{
  "kid": "ABCDPK1",
  "alg": "RS256"
}

BODY

{
  "iss": "https://appleid.apple.com",
  "aud": "XYZ.App",
  "exp": 1574131940,
  "iat": 1574131340,
  "sub": "01234.1234561ecd054cd285d65cc7af261958.0123",
  "c_hash": "ABCDe-csTpNdUa0Eri5wFw",
  "email": "user@privaterelay.appleid.com",
  "email_verified": "true",
  "is_private_email": "true",
  "auth_time": 1574131340
}
```

## Problem

When I make use of the [Firebase Authentication REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/?authuser=0#section-verify-custom-token) to try and exchange a custom token for an ID and refresh token I get the following message (and yes, I have made sure the token wasn't expired when I used it) :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "INVALID_CUSTOM_TOKEN",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I was hoping that the new "Apple" sign-in method in Firebase Authentication would take care of that, once configured, and I could just pass in the JWT token from Apple. Am I missing a step ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I guess I found the answer to my own question shortly after posting this (of course...).

I was using the wrong API endpoint. Instead I needed to use the [Sign-in with OAuth credentials](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/?authuser=0#section-sign-in-with-oauth-credential) endpoint :

```
https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithIdp?key={{apiKey}}

to get back : 

{
  "federatedId": "apple.com/ABCDEF.ABCDEF261958.1234",
  "providerId": "apple.com",
  "email": "user@privaterelay.appleid.com",
  "emailVerified": true,
  "localId": "123456786RbgQgxhzfSpyIJGLPIw1",
  "idToken": "eyJABCDEFG.ABCDEFG.ABCDEFGiFQ",
  "refreshToken": "AEu4IL1CY_PGF...6pN0DuQ",
  "expiresIn": "3600",
  "oauthIdToken": "eyJraWQiO...CJHHrxeg",
  "rawUserInfo": "[JWT token info]",
  "isNewUser": true,
  "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyAssertionResponse",
  "pendingToken": "AMzJoSn...HkvLeaOmFjNlcw"
}
```

The provided POST body should look something like :

```
{
    "postBody": "id_token=eyJraWQiOiJBSURPUABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP.eyABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP2.KW0JABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP&providerId=apple.com",
    "requestUri": "https://gpsstreaming.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler",
    "returnIdpCredential": true,
    "returnSecureToken": true
}
```

Note that the id_token is the 3-dot-notation token (JWT token) provided by Apple's Sign In With Apple [ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/asauthorizationappleidcredential) -- data obfuscated here for obvious reasons. For example if you use SwiftUI, you get that from the [completionBlock](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/signinwithapplebutton/3679026-init) of the SignInWithAppleButton.

Comment: What is the `postBody` that you provided? I am trying various combinations of `accessToken`, `idToken`, and `providerId` but it is not working for me.

Comment: @Charles, I updated my answer to include the POST body info (partially obfuscated).

Comment: Don't forget the "&providerId=apple.com" at the end of the postBody.

Comment: Hi @Nick, did you need to provide "nonce" value ?

Comment: @Kapusch, I have only tried without the nonce for the REST API; it worked fine for me (that was a while back). I am using the `nonce` with the iOS SDK and it works fine. However I haven't tried providing an incorrect nonce for either case. I'll test it out if I have time tomorrow but otherwise you should be able to put the nonce in the postBody if you've provided it in the sign-in with apple step.

Comment: Hi @Nick, it's okay now, I've been able to achieve Firebase authentication thanks to IDToken returned by Xamarin.Essentials Web Authenticator. Thanks for your answer !